# Notify bunching object with abstract methods

Tags: ruby, module

What I'd like to:

- notify bunching objects in order:　B -> C -> D
- separate the notification methods to module.

Then I wrote the code below:

```rb
module AbstractModule
def notifiable?
    raise "this should be overriden"
end

def observers
    raise "this should be overriden"
end

def notify
    puts "#{self.class.to_s} notification"
end

def notify_all
    notify
    observers.map{|o| o.notify_all} if observers && notifiable?
end
end

class B
    include AbstractModule
    def observers
        c_objects = 2.times.map{ C.new }
    end

    def notifiable?
        true
    end
end

class C
    include AbstractModule
    def observers
        d_objects = 3.times.map{ D.new }
    end
    def notifiable?
        true
    end
end

class D
    include AbstractModule
    def observers
        nil
    end
    def notifiable?
        false
    end
end

obj = B.new
obj.notify_all
```

Actually it's my desired result and the result is :

```
B notification
C notification
D notification
D notification
D notification
C notification
D notification
D notification
D notification
```

But I'm dissatisfied with :

- B,C,D must implement `observers` and `notifiable` methods

How do I refactor this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is based on [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) - you should not create abstract methods. Simply *assume* that they there, and if they are not - an error is thrown. Where you want to be sure that a specific method is available, use [`respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F)

```
module Notifiable
  def notify
    puts "#{self.class.to_s} notification"
  end

  def notify_all
    notify
    observers.map{|o| o.notify_all} if respond_to?(:observers) && observers
  end
end

class B
  include Notifiable
  def observers
    c_objects = 2.times.map{ C.new }
  end
end

class C
  include Notifiable
  def observers
    d_objects = 3.times.map{ D.new }
  end
end

class D
  include Notifiable
end

obj = B.new
obj.notify_all
```